# Microsoft MapPoint 18.0 object library in VB 6.0

Tags: dll, vb6, mappoint

I am using Microsoft MapPoint 18.0 object library as a reference in VB 6.0 . After creating an object and passing the address parameters , the program doesnt return any latitude,longitude data for any valid address. was wondering if this is a dll issue for VB 6.0 ?

Comment: You should be able to, but we have no idea what you are actually doing. Post your code and a description of where it is going wrong. Are valid objects being returned? Have you checked their other properties? Etc

Answer (score 3):

I just did a quick test using the reference "Microsoft MapPoint 19.0 Object Library (North America)" and the following code worked for me:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim mmpApp As MapPoint.Application, mmpMap As MapPoint.Map, _
        mmpFindResults As MapPoint.FindResults

Set mmpApp = New MapPoint.Application
Set mmpMap = mmpApp.ActiveMap

Set mmpFindResults = mmpMap.FindAddressResults( _
        "24 Sussex Drive", _
        "Ottawa", _
        "", _
        "ON", _
        "", _
        MapPoint.GeoCountry.geoCountryCanada)

If mmpFindResults.ResultsQuality = geoFirstResultGood Then
    MsgBox "First result returned: (" & mmpFindResults(1).Latitude & "," & _
            mmpFindResults(1).Longitude & ")"
Else
    MsgBox "The search returned poor, ambiguous, or non-existent results"
End If

Set mmpFindResults = Nothing
Set mmpMap = Nothing
Set mmpApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

I expect that it would also work under the 18.0 version.

Comment: Yes it should work, but we don't know what the OP is/isn't doing. I would also note that your code is blindly assuming there is at least one good result returned. Before fetching the coordinate information, you should check the Results collection's ResultsQuality property.

Comment: It is a common problem that I see ("Why does this code crash?") - not helped by the examples in the documentation which also exclude the test!